# Problemas al hacer copy con archivos de otro ordenador

Tags: php, wamp

Estoy tratando de hacer copy con imagenes de un WAMP local.
La imagen es accesible, pero con este comando especifico da errores.

```
$url = "http://192.168.1.66/c/fotos/B00GO1MG8I.jpg";
$dest = "img.jpg";
copy($url,$dest);
```

El error que sale es el siguiente.

```
Warning: copy(http://192.168.1.66/c/fotos/B00JZFG6QS.jpg): failed to open stream: Connection timed out.
```

Comment: Sólo es un warning, posiblemente porque esa imagen B00JZFG6QS.jpg no existe.

Comment: ¿Tienes permitida la salida a Internet del servicio de apache? Si desde un navegador ese archivo se ve pero desde PHP no, es probable que el firewall de la máquina donde tienes el WAMP esté impidiendo que el proceso apache pueda establecer conexiones hacia el exterior, las filtra y por eso te aparece "connection timeout".

Comment: Intente ingresa a la direccion de la imagen y no se puede acceder al archivo. Si la direccion es tuya, trata de permitir conexiones de lo contrario jamas vas a poder usar el copy()

Comment: No puedes usar URL para copiar, en todo caso, fopen() con la directiva allow_url_fopen activada, o bien, con cURL().